# Android kernel .config file for Netfilter and iptables

Tags: android, linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter

The latest android sources(android 4.0.1) come with Iptables 1.4.11.

In order to enable iptables and Netfilter, how should the 2.6..35 kernel look like?

I googled some sites and got the following config. Do I need to do some changes?
Is XTABLES even needed?  I need to use iptable nat rules the rest is not a priority.
Please see this config (only th networking part is given below) and advise:

```
#
# Core Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_ACCT=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_GRE=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_UDPLITE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_AMANDA=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_H323=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IRC=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_NETBIOS_NS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PPTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SANE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SIP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CLASSIFY=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNMARK is not set
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_DSCP is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFQUEUE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFLOG=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NOTRACK is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_RATEEST=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TRACE is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPMSS=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPOPTSTRIP is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNBYTES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNLIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DSCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ESP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HELPER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPRANGE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_LENGTH=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MAC=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OWNER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_POLICY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_PKTTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_QUOTA=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RATEEST=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_REALM=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATISTIC=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STRING=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TCPMSS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TIME=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_U32=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HASHLIMIT=y

#
# IP: Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_QUEUE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_RECENT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ECN=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_AH=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TTL=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REJECT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ULOG=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_NETMAP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_SNMP_BASIC=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_GRE=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_UDPLITE=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_IRC=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_AMANDA=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PPTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_H323=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_SIP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ECN=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TTL=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_CLUSTERIP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPFILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARP_MANGLE=y
# CONFIG_IP_DCCP is not set
# CONFIG_IP_SCTP is not set
# CONFIG_TIPC is not set
# CONFIG_ATM is not set
# CONFIG_BRIDGE is not set
# CONFIG_VLAN_8021Q is not set
# CONFIG_DECNET is not set
# CONFIG_LLC2 is not set
# CONFIG_IPX is not set
# CONFIG_ATALK is not set
# CONFIG_X25 is not set
# CONFIG_LAPB is not set
# CONFIG_ECONET is not set
# CONFIG_WAN_ROUTER is not set
# CONFIG_NET_SCHED is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_ROUTE=y

#
# Network testing
#
# CONFIG_NET_PKTGEN is not set
# CONFIG_HAMRADIO is not set
# CONFIG_CAN is not set
# CONFIG_IRDA is not set
CONFIG_BT=y
CONFIG_BT_L2CAP=y
CONFIG_BT_SCO=y
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM=y
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM_TTY=y
CONFIG_BT_BNEP=y
# CONFIG_BT_BNEP_MC_FILTER is not set
# CONFIG_BT_BNEP_PROTO_FILTER is not set
CONFIG_BT_HIDP=y
```

Answer (score 0):

For just IP tables, I added the following to my linux kernel config:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MASQUERADE=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT=m
```