# Connecting Android Emulator to Remote System

Tags: android, linux, networking, android-emulator, iptables

I have 2 ubuntu systems A and B.

A's IP addr is 192.168.0.5
B's IP addr is 192.168.0.3

System A runs Android Emulator. I have a TCP Client App which has to communicate with System B.

Since the Android Apps can only "see" localhost(as 10.0.2.2), the client App sends message to 10.0.2.2 at port Pb.

Now I am assuming that System A should see to that whatever message it receives on its localhost(i.e 127.0.0.1 which is 10.0.2.2 for emulator) at port Pb must be forwarded to System B 192.168.0.3 at port Pb. Therefore I set up the following on System A:

echo "1" < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 --dport *Pb* -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.3:*Pb*

System B runs a TCP Server at IP 192.168.0.3 and port Pb

With these rules in place on System A and B, I start the android Emulator on System A and then the TCP Client App on Andoid.

Wireshark tool shows packages arriving at 127.0.0.1 but my Server at System B does not receive any packets at all :(

What is wrong?

```
--------------------              --------------------------

  System A                        System B
  192.168.0.5 wlan0               192.168.0.3 wlan0
  127.0.0.1   lo                  127.0.0.1 lo
                <---------------->

  Android EMULATOR                TCP Server
  TCP CLient App                  at 192.168.0.3, port Pb
  at 10.0.2.2
----------------------            ----------------------------
```

Please help.

Comment: I think maybe you are confused about where you need forwarding.  Android emulators can generate outbound traffic all by themselves (ie, you can visit real websites from the android browser), but what the emulator program refuses to do is to listen for connections on non-local interfaces of the host system.  So where you need to set up forwarding with non-android tools is from system B's external network interface to its local emulator alias address in order to get the incoming connection into emulator B.

Comment: Or if I am misunderstanding and the system B tcp server is not running under android, then you should not be needing to do any special forwarding at all - your case is that same as contacting a real webserver from the browser on the android emulator, and that just works.

Comment: Thanks Chris.System A runs Android Emu with IP addr 192.168.0.5 & System B is an ubuntu system running TCP Server prog on IP addr 192.168.0.3. Yay! The Client App WORKS when I gave server IP addr of System B instead of 10.0.2.2 just like you said! Suppose if I have another Android Emulator on B which receives the messages from A, how can I route the Emulator messages on B to the host system B ? My ultimate goal is to have android A<-->android B<-->Linux connection where android B routes packets received on one interface to another which here, is Linux system( or host system B). Could you help?

Comment: Routing between entworks would need to be its own question, but generally it's pretty tricky to get a physical android device talking on two interfaces (wifi and mobile) at the same time without either rooting and mucking about in the device specific network configuration or using a tethering mode.  For your forwarding into the emulator you can probably use what you were trying above, you just need to set it up on the incoming side rather than outgoing.

Comment: ok Thanks Chris. I am going to write a new post as follow up. I have a rooted android device and I already compiled it with iptables. However there seems to be a bug. Please do take a look at my posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208298/android-kernel-config-file-for-netfilter-and-iptables and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175984/iptables-1-4-11-on-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331699/getprotobyname-error-iptables